# appending html data to bootstrap modal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am passing data to a bootstrap modal using and id and linking that id with stored data.

```
$("#fruit").html($(this).data("fruit"));
```

I am also appending data to the bootstrap modal

```
$('#mymodal').find('.modal-body').append('<p>sample text</p>');
```

But when i try the below it does not seem to work

```
$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>.html($(this).data("fruit"))</p>");
```

Comment: This looks wrong: .append("<p>.html($(this).data("fruit"))</p>")

Comment: sting manipulation is little wrong. Try this :$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>.html("+$(this).data("fruit")+")</p>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working because jQuery method which you written in append method treated as string.

Replace this code

```
$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>.html($(this).data("fruit"))</p>");
```

With

```
$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>.html("+$(this).data("fruit")+")</p>");
```

Comment: For some reason i am getting "html(correct value of fruit)" on the screen.

Comment: If you want to remove html() from the output, Please use this code. `$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>"+$(this).data("fruit")+"</p>");`

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem in your string. Since you are using JS with string, you need to use `+` to append them.

So this

```
$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>.html($(this).data("fruit"))</p>");
```

should be

```
$("#mymodal").find(".modal-body").append("<p>" + $('#fruit').html() + "</p>");
```